# Parsing annotation meta data from an ejb proxy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, ejb-3.1

I have a single business interface that is implemented by multiple stateless beans.
Each implementation has a annotation at Class level with a unique value.
I use CDI injection as

```
@Any Instance<MyInterface> implementations;
```

I want to look up a specific implemenattion based a value (which matches the annotation value).
Now since all implementations are EJBs I get an EJB proxy and unable to parse annotation. Please suggest a way to parse the annotation meta data from the proxy.

Also what are the other ways to get the EJB other than JNDI look up in above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDI provides a way to select an implementation without having to parse annotation.

Create MyAnnotationQualifier class by

```
extends AnnotationLiteral<MyAnnotation> implements MyAnnotation
```

Now in the CDI implementations variable above select my impl as:

```
implementations.select(new MyQualifer("myValue"));
```

Reference:

Section 4.10: 
http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.0.3.Final/en-US/html/injection.html#lookup

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you an example of how to create an EJB-Factory:

Given the interface:

```
@Local
public interface Car {

    String uname();
}
```

We have two implementations:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Ferrari implements Car {

    @Override
    public String uname() {
        return "Ferrari";
    }
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Lamborgini implements Car {

    @Override
    public String uname() {
        return "Lamborgini";
    }
}
```

Now we want to create a Qualifier to distinguish between them:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface CarModel {

    public Brand value();

    public enum Brand {
        FERRARI,
        LAMBORGINI
    }
}
```

So our factory now looks like:

```
@Stateless
public class CarFactory {

    @EJB(beanName = "Ferrari") // beanName or mappedName to lookup for the EJBs
    Car ferrari;

    @EJB(beanName = "Lamborgini")
    Car lamborgini;

    @Produces
    @CarModel(CarModel.Brand.FERRARI)
    public Car pimpMyRideA() { // Factory Method
        return ferrari;
    }

    @Produces
    @CarModel(CarModel.Brand.LAMBORGINI)
    public Car pimpMyRideB() { // Factory Method
        return lamborgini;
    }
}
```

And that's all, now we are able to @Inject the EJB's:

```
@WebServlet(name = "CarServlet", urlPatterns = {"/CarServlet"})
public class CarServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject // EJB injected!
    @CarModel(CarModel.Brand.FERRARI)
    Car car;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("We have a > " + car.uname());
        }    
    }
}
```

Now, *We have a > Ferrari* that is a Stateless EJB.

There is a github project > https://github.com/sdmoralesma/smorales-ejbfactory

### EDIT

Additionally, if you prefer Lookup in a fluent way, please refer to this post that implements a **Bean Locator** pattern:

http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_1_beanlocator_when

Comment: Thanks . I was looking for a way to programmatically look up instead of static injection.

Comment: @Inv3r53 well, I've edited the answer for future reference adding other way to do the lookups.